# Using OpenLayers 3 spyglass?

Tags: openlayers, jquery

I would like to use OpenLayers 3 spyglass example inside my project.

The problem is when I want to use selection for layer, which will be inside spyglass circle. I can't get it working, I don't know how to update it on every user's selection correctly.

Anyone more skilled can help me?

Here is my fiddle with it partially working:
http://jsfiddle.net/dkcz/8a3pdavv/

Comment: The first issue I can see is that what is selected in your select box is just a string with the layer name, not an object representing the layer. You would need to do a call to map.getLayers, check if the layer name matches that of your select box, and then add the pre/post compose events to that. See [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/2848) for a bit more.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more at this point. I'm still getting my head round OL3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example that accomplishes what you want (I think):
http://jsfiddle.net/tschaub/Lkgx0qaa/

I've created a map with three layers, only the first one (named `roads`) is visible:

```js
var roads = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.BingMaps({key: key, imagerySet: 'Road'})
});

var clipped = {
  imagery: new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({key: key, imagerySet: 'Aerial'}),
    visible: false
  }),
  labeled: new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({key: key, imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabels'}),
    visible: false
  })
};

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [roads, clipped.imagery, clipped.labeled],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([-109, 46.5], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 6
  })
});
```

The `imagery` and `labeled` layers are going to be toggled on/off with radio inputs.  When a radio input is checked, the layer is made visible (with [`layer.setVisible(true)`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#setVisible)), and listeners are registered for `precompose` and `postcompse` events (with [`layer.on(...)`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#on)).

In addition, any previously chosen layer will be made invisible (with [`layer.setVisible(false)`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#setVisible)), and listeners will be unregistered (with [`layer.un(...)`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#un)).

The function that handles this radio change event looks like this:

```js
var chosen;
function onRadioChange(event) {
  if (chosen) {
    chosen.un('precompose', onPreCompose);
    chosen.un('postcompose', onPostCompose);
    chosen.setVisible(false);
  }
  chosen = clipped[event.target.value];
  chosen.on('precompose', onPreCompose);
  chosen.on('postcompose', onPostCompose);
  chosen.setVisible(true);
}
```

That's really the meat of the solution.  The rest pretty much follows the hosted [layer-spy.html example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/layer-spy.html).

For completeness, I'll dump the rest below.

```js
// get the pixel position with every move
var mousePosition = null;
map.on('pointermove', function(event) {
  mousePosition = event.pixel
  map.render();
});

// before rendering the layer, do some clipping
function onPreCompose(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  var pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  if (mousePosition) {
    // only show a circle around the mouse
    ctx.arc(mousePosition[0] * pixelRatio, mousePosition[1] * pixelRatio,
        75 * pixelRatio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5 * pixelRatio;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.clip();
}

// after rendering the layer, restore the canvas context
function onPostCompose(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.restore();
}

// listen for change events on radio inputs
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0, ii = inputs.length; i < ii; ++i) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', onRadioChange);
}

// kick things off with the first checked radio input
onRadioChange({target: document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked')});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It is almost exactly what I need - except I would like to select my layers from select box with almost 50 options(=layers). I will try to implement your solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried everything with my (unfortunately limited) JavaScript knowledge to set the clip dynamically on the selected layer. I couldn't manage to save and restore the whole canvas context, neither the layer's one. I have tried to unbind the event from the layer, no luck. Neither `strUser.un(evt, func)` or `evt.stopPropagation()` worked out. For this, I considered the clipped layer unrecoverable and came up with a hack to solve this problem.

I have created 3 clipped layers along with the 3 original ones, then removed and added them systematically based on user choice.

HTML input:

```
<select onChange="change(this.value)" id="mySelect">
    <option label="roads" value="roads" selected></option>
    <option label="imagery" value="imagery"></option>
    <option label="osm" value="osm" selected></option>
```

Layer creation:

```
var roads = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
  });
  var roads_clipped = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
  });

  var imagery = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.Stamen({
        layer: 'watercolor'
      })
    });
      var imagery_clipped = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.Stamen({
        layer: 'watercolor'
      })
    });

  var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      visible: true
  });
  var osm_clipped = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      visible: true
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [roads, imagery, osm_clipped],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([-109, 46.5], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 6
      })
  });
```

Note that, I have added the clipped version of the `osm` layer instead of the normal version, to initialize the spyglass.

Events (mouse position and clipping):

```
  var mousePosition = null;
  $(map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function (evt) {
      mousePosition = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
      map.render();
  }).on('mouseout', function () {
      mousePosition = null;
      map.render();
  });

  osm_clipped.on('precompose', function(event) {
      var ctx = event.context;
      var pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      if (mousePosition) {
          // only show a circle around the mouse
          ctx.arc(mousePosition[0] * pixelRatio, mousePosition[1] * pixelRatio,
          radius * pixelRatio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.lineWidth = 5 * pixelRatio;
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
          ctx.stroke();
      }
      ctx.clip();
  });

  // after rendering the layer, restore the canvas context
  osm_clipped.on('postcompose', function(event) {
      var ctx = event.context;
      ctx.restore();
  });

  imagery_clipped.on('precompose', function(event) {
      var ctx = event.context;
      var pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      if (mousePosition) {
          ctx.arc(mousePosition[0] * pixelRatio, mousePosition[1] * pixelRatio,
          radius * pixelRatio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.lineWidth = 5 * pixelRatio;
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
          ctx.stroke();
      }
      ctx.clip();
  });

  imagery_clipped.on('postcompose', function(event) {
      var ctx = event.context;
      ctx.restore();
  });

  roads_clipped.on('precompose', function(event) {
      var ctx = event.context;
      var pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      if (mousePosition) {
          ctx.arc(mousePosition[0] * pixelRatio, mousePosition[1] * pixelRatio,
          radius * pixelRatio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.lineWidth = 5 * pixelRatio;
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
          ctx.stroke();
      }
      ctx.clip();
  });

  roads_clipped.on('postcompose', function(event) {
      var ctx = event.context;
      ctx.restore();
  });
```

Global variable to store the last clipped layer:

```
var strUser = document.getElementById('mySelect').value;
```

Change function:

```
function change(e) {
    map.removeLayer(eval(strUser + '_clipped'));  //remove the last added clipped layer
    map.getLayers().getArray().splice(0,0,eval(strUser));  //add the normal version of it to the bottom of the stack
    strUser = e;  //get the new selection
    map.removeLayer(eval(strUser));  //remove the normal version of the new selection
    map.addLayer(eval(strUser + '_clipped'));  //add the clipped version
};
```

Also note, that you can evaluate a string as a variable with `eval()`, if the variable exists on the same name as the string. Be sure that the `<option>` values match the variable names for the layers.

Hint: one of the core OL developers, @[erilem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/6324/erilem) can be found on this site. Maybe he can provide a proper solution, if you ask him nicely with the link to this question.